# How to create a Repository with EF core for a Value object in asp.net Boilerplate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have created a second dbContext using the ABP .net core startup template.
This all works fine, but the second dbContext is only used to extract data out of a view.

I have a class that maps to the view, but this view has no primary key.
And *if* it were to have a primary key, it would be a composed key.

So I can't derive that class from Entity, so I chose to derive it from ValueObject.

But ABP doesn't create repositories for ValueObjects afaik.

So my question is, how to create a custom .net core repository for a ValueObject. (I only need an implementation of GetAll, since it will be a readonly repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive from Entity and configure your view in OnModelCreating of your DbContext to map Id property to a column.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("YourColumn");
```

Otherwise you can get by dependency injection IDbContextProvider service and use it like a simple DbContext

```
private readonly IDbContextProvider<TDbContext> _dbContextProvider;

public YourService(IDbContextProvider<TDbContext> dbContextProvider)
{
    _dbContextProvider = dbContextProvider;
}

public void MethodName(){
    var context = _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();
    context.YourEntity.OrderBy(a => a.Name);
}
```

Comment: Your first solution isn't possible, since I don't have a single column to map. The key is composed of several columns. I ended up using a variation of your second suggestion, by using the IDbContextProvider  to create a Generic Reader (instead of a Repository) that I can apply to ValueObjects.